# Why don't browser developer tools display input field values?

Tags: javascript

When I inspect an input field that has a value, the value appears empty in the debugger like this:

[image]

I was just wondering why? Debugger performance? Or perhaps something related to security? Or maybe I need to switch something on/off?

The reason why I am wondering is that it makes debugging more difficult for me in certain situations, like right now when the field loads empty while console logged `.value` returns the value that is supposed to load but didn't for some reason:

```
console.log( 'before LoadFromLocalStorage' );
console.log( 'input element:' );
console.log( document.getElementById( 'email' ) );
console.log( 'input element value:' );
console.log( document.getElementById( 'email' ).value );



document.getElementById( 'email' ).value = sessionStorage.email;


console.log( 'after LoadFromLocalStorage' );
console.log( 'input element:' );
console.log( document.getElementById( 'email' ) );
console.log( 'input element value:' );
console.log( document.getElementById( 'email' ).value );
```

[image]

P.S. it actually shows up in the field when I set timeout long enough. 1ms is enough in about 75% of tests, but sometimes it fails to show up even with 100ms timeout. So apparently something is going on during that time, but I have no idea what. It would be really nice if I could log when it actually appears in the input field.

---

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem with the empty input field. I used `element.innerHTML += "a lot of html"` elsewhere in my code and due to its destructive nature it wiped all the input fields before it completed appending html. I replaced it with [`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#Syntax) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place.

The `value` **attribute** represents the **default** value, which you aren't modifying.

The current value appears in the DOM `value` **property**.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's very neat! I played with it for a while and its accurate, although it doesn't update in real time like dom elements when they flash when you change something. I now know that something clears my input field afterwards so I got to go figure out what.